# Heroku - how can I configure my dynos sleeping

Tags: python, heroku, bots

I have two telegram bots running on heroku. They just execute the main method of my python file, waiting for incoming commands from the users. So they have a simple web container, which is started with the command `python script.py`.
The first app sleeps after not receiving any commands for an hour. The second one runs 24/7 and is eating my free hours.

I have checked all the settings and configuration of these two apps. I cannot find any difference. Why would they run differently?

Procfile (app which behaves as I want, sleeping when not active):

```
web: python main.py
```

Procfile of the other app:

```
web: python main.py ${PORT}
```

Comment: Please post your Procfile

Comment: @YoniRabinovitch I've added my Procfiles.

Comment: Why are the Procfiles different?

Comment: Thought they cannot run on the same port. But i've tested it now and remove the ´${PORT}´. But it didn't change anything.